# Modal, variables passed using resolve binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-modal

I have the following directive

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('warningDirective',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      showwarning: '=',
      warningmessage: '=',
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $uibModal, $element) {
      $scope.$watch('showwarning', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (angular.isDefined(newVal)  && newVal != oldVal && newVal) {
          $scope.open();
        }
      });
      $scope.open = function () {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'warningModal.html',
          resolve: {
            warningMessage: function() {
              return $scope.warningmessage;
            },
            showWarning: function() {
              return $scope.showwarning;
            }
          },
          windowClass: 'warning-modal',
          controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, warningMessage, showWarning) {
            $scope.warningMessage = warningMessage;
            $scope.showWarning = showWarning;
            $scope.confirmWarning = function () {
              //action here
              $scope.showWarning = false;
              $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            }
            $scope.closeModal = function () {
              $scope.showWarning = false;
              $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

This is a reusable directive to show a modal warning (later on I will pass a yes action function). Inside the directive I am watching scope variable `showwarning`, when it's true to show the popup. I am passing it using resolve and setting it to `false` when user closes the modal or clicks yes.

My problem is that it's not getting updated. Later on when I set `showwarning` to `true` in my controller, it won't trigger the watch since `showwarning` is still `true`.

Here is [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SI6OcLDrp3iaT95zgvtQ?p=preview).

The modal will only show once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change `showwarning` to false whenever the modal closes.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/hQ3kZZDo0rwzfKFw9PUX?p=preview)**

```
$scope.open = function() {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    // modal options
  });

  // set showwarning to false
  modalInstance.result.finally(function() {
    $scope.showwarning = false;
  });

};
```

Comment: Thanks, that did really help..But what's the "rule" here ? variables passed to the modal controller are not binded ?

Comment: They are binded. AngularJS only triggers the watch handlers when there are changes to the watched value. When you set the `showwarning` value to true, it triggers the watch handler for `showwarning`. But when you close `showwarning` it is still true. So setting `showwarning` to true again wouldn't trigger the watch handler, since `showwarning` didn't change its value at all.

Comment: But in the closeModal and confirmWarning functions I have $scope.showWarning = false;

Comment: That is because the `$scope` that you're setting `$scope.showWarning` to false is of the modal's controller not the scope of the directive.

Comment: Ok, here is another plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/w9L1RGypFKPqtvYFfxG6?p=preview , how come I am able to update the dropdown from the modal's controller ?

Comment: That is because you are updating a reference of the `container` array. As opposed with the `showwarning` value is a primitive value.

Comment: This is another **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/88gfnqLs/1/)** that is somehow similar to your case.

Comment: That makes sense! I feel stupid not figuring out this by myself, great examples, thanks again.